# Donut Chart Multiple Radial Lines

Tags: css, charts, sass

I have created a donut chart with multiple content, I dont want to use libraries so i created a native one with pure css ... Its done!

The problem is, i need to create radial buttons like this

[image]

and I created something like this

```css
.swiper-slide {
     transition: all 1s;
     height: 180px !important;
     width: 180px !important;
     background: #fff;
     border-radius: 16px;
     margin-top: 16px;
     margin-left: 16px;
     margin-bottom: 16px;
     width: calc(100% - 32px) !important;
}
 .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-prev {
     margin-left: 40px;
}
 .swiper-slide:last-child {
     margin-left: 8px;
}
 .swiper-slide .col {
     display: grid;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-family: "Aeonik Regular";
}
 .swiper-slide .col .chip {
     padding: 2px;
     height: 10px;
     width: 25px;
     margin-right: 5px;
}
 .swiper-slide .col .chip.family {
     background-color: #f5ba19;
}
 .swiper-slide .col .chip.health {
     background-color: #15f987;
}
 .swiper-slide .col .chip.work {
     background-color: #33127a;
}
 .swiper-slide .col .chip.others {
     background-color: #ef4d8e;
}
 .swiper-slide .col .donut {
     width: auto;
     height: 180px;
     display: grid;
     place-items: center;
}
 .swiper-slide .col .donut .circle {
     height: 147px;
     width: 147px;
     border-radius: 147px;
     display: grid;
     place-items: center;
     background: conic-gradient(#f5ba19 0deg 45deg, #15f987 45deg 110deg, #33127a 110deg 200deg, #ef4d8e 200deg);
}
 .swiper-slide .col .donut .circle .inner-circle {
     height: 115px;
     width: 115px;
     border-radius: 115px;
     background-color: #fff;
     display: grid;
     place-items: center;
}
 .swiper-slide .col .donut .circle .inner-circle .balance .col {
     display: inline-flex;
     align-items: flex-start;
}
 .swiper-slide .col .donut .circle .inner-circle .balance .col span {
     font-family: "Poppins Medium";
     font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 18px;
}
 .swiper-slide .col .donut .circle .inner-circle .balance .col span:first-child {
     font-family: "Roboto Bold";
}
 .swiper-slide .col .donut .circle .inner-circle .balance .col span.int {
     line-height: 24px;
     font-size: 24px;
     margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <div class="row"><div class="col"><div class="donut"><div class="circle"><div class="inner-circle"><div class="balance row"><div class="col"><span>$</span><span class="int">0</span><span>00</span></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="col"><p><div class="family chip"></div>Família</p><p><div class="health chip"></div>Saúde</p><p><div class="work chip"></div>Trabalho</p><p><div class="others chip"></div>Outros</p></div></div>
</div>
```

Someone can help me with this?

PS: I used conic-gradient, i dont know if it is the better way ...

Comment: Frankly, use an SVG...simpler all round...and you can style the end caps

Comment: Hmm good idea, i ll try